# Suggestions for Working with Uncooperative / apathetic teammates

Tags: research-process, masters, presentation, collaboration

I am getting very frustrated / angry in working with my research teammates on a capstone course project in my Masters program. The project we are working is fairly complex and includes a good amount of data gathering, analysis, and interpretation. Its getting very close to the deadline, and I am very interested in making our project of superior quality.

This will be presented in front of two faculty professors. However, my team mates don't seem to have the same dedication as I do and seems apathetic to the end result. I am getting very frustrated as a poor research product reflects badly on myself. Direct talk does not seem to help.

For background, my teammates are all from an Asian background and are new to the United States. Perhaps the language complexity could be part of the explanation?

Thanks and I appreciate any feedback you people may provide!

Comment: @ff524 this question does have some differences from the previous question.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Great, if you think so, please [edit] it to highlight the specific differences. (To me, both seem like general questions on working with unmotivated teammates.)